# How do i render this water correctly?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

Im quite new to Blender, i was following a tutorial on how to make a water surface, and although it looks great in the shading and in the layout tab when i render the animation it looks really dark and opaque, as if the material or the shading wasnt working at all.
Im sure its something quite simple, but itd be great if someone could lend me a hand. Thanks!

[image]

once rendered it looks like this

[image]

Here's the file [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome, did you add an HDRI to your world to have reflection and light?

Comment: https://youtu.be/JM-Z4F3WtmI?t=80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an HDRI image, otherwise your surface has nothing to reflect. In *Material Preview* mode you'll have a default HDRI, that's why you see a reflection.

Go into the *Shader Editor*, switch to *World*, activate the *Node Wrangler* addon, select the *Background* node, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to create a node chain with an *Environment* node, and load an HDRI:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was it!